# Rails Active Record search based on belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a **country** which has many **areas** which has many **shops**.

> Country > Areas > Shops.

I want to return a list of all shops based on the country, not the area. Something like this:

```
@shops = Shops.find(some query based on country = America).
```

Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails-y way to query a model with a belongs\_to association](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13619560/rails-y-way-to-query-a-model-with-a-belongs-to-association)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to the Rails' documentation on joining tables. Specifically, look at the subsection labeled "12.2.4 Joining Nested Associations (Multiple Level)":

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#using-array-hash-of-named-associations

Your query will probably end up looking something like this (though you may need to check the pluralization on some of the symbols):

```
@shops = Shop.joins(:area => :countries).where(:countries => {:name => 'America'})
```

Answer (score 2):

Is your shop belongs_to area, area belongs_to country? If so, maybe you can do something like this.

```
class Country
  has_many :areas
  has_many :shops, through: :areas
end

class Area
  belongs_to :country
end

class Shop
  belongs_to :area
end
```

so you can just use something like this: `@country.shops`